# In "Prism 6" how to bind viewmodel to model

Tags: prism

Please explain to me how to use this method:

```
AutoWireViewModelChanged(object view, Action<object, object> setDataContextCallback)
```

What is the best way to bind view and viewmodel?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call that method from code to bind view and viewmodel. You simply add this line to the xaml of your view and the binding will happen automatically. If you want to read deeper into this topic, [check this paragraph](http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/05-Implementing-MVVM/#creating-the-view-model-using-a-view-model-locator) in the official documentation.

```
ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="true"
```

You can check [this sample](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows/blob/master/SplitViewSample/SplitViewSample/Views/MainPage.xaml#L8) on the Prism GitHub repository to see a working example.

Comment: but when we should use the method AutoWireViewModelChanged(object view, Action<object, object> setDataContextCallback) ?